# lost hard drive while upgrading

Tags: installation, upgrade

While upgrading from 12.04 to 13.04, everything appeared to be going fine until the very end when a couple of quick red failed messages appeared during final cleanup. The desktop screen lost all icons and froze.

I am using an OCZ 120 GB solid state sata drive. My bios can see it but my original 12.04 booted from my thumb drive can't. Any ideas on how to get access to the drive so I can reformat and try a fresh install of 13.04?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to boot into Ubuntu 12.04 and then upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04. If you want to install Ubuntu 13.04, download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (choose 32 bit or 64 bit) and put it on a CD or USB. Then, restart your computer and press F12 or another function key (based on your system) to boot from the CD or USB. Then, you can hit Try Ubuntu if you want to try and recover your data, otherwise hit Install Ubuntu and follow the remaining directions to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 13.04.